# How to update a dynamic field name in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I want to do something like the below code in React Native:

```
await firestore()
      .collection('Users')
      .doc('ABC')
      .update({
        this.state.documentName: url,
      });
```

But I need `this.state.documentName` to be dynamic but VSCode is reporting an error saying `':' expected.`. What am I missing?

[image: Image of TypeScript annotation]

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @PandhuWibowo ':' expected between this.state, I have updated the question with a screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close, in order to compute the field name, wrap it in square brackets:

```
await firestore()
      .collection('Users')
      .doc('ABC')
      .update({
        [this.state.documentName]: url,
      });
```

The [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) method also accepts arguments in key-value pairs:

```
await firestore()
      .collection('Users')
      .doc('ABC')
      .update(this.state.documentName, url);
```

**Note**: You should make sure to employ appropriate [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to prevent a user from promoting themselves to an admin if that information is also contained in their user document.

Answer (score 0):

Define the documentName from state outside of the async function in a variable then use it to update in the function

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var documentName = this.state.documentName;
await db.collection("Users")
.doc('ABC')
.update({documentName: "bar"});
```